# How do I customise desktop effects and toggle between comopsiting window mangers in KDE on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: kde

How do I customise the desktop effects in KDE like Aero Snap, Aero Peek and much more?

I know that these effects are enabled by the compositing window manager for KDE which is KWin. But what if I want to use Compiz? How do I toggle between Compiz and KWin in Ubuntu 10.10? Does the Fusion Icon still work, or should I use Displex?

Comment: Then install Compiz, but then i'm not sure if it would be a good idea to keep it like that how do you toggle between them? compiz --replace` `kwin --replace` (if it's not kwin put the correct name of the process)

Comment: @UriHerrera does the Fusion Icon work in Ubuntu 10.10? Because it doesn't work on Ubuntu 11.10. Is Displex a suitable alternative?

Comment: Fusion icon works in 10.10.

Comment: @severin Can you please turn this into an answer so I can mark it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can toggle compositing in 10.10 with fusion-icon

`sudo apt-get install fusion-icon` will install it.

then simply run fusion-icon and you can turn on/off compositing and select the window manager you want to use.